# Why doesn't WSL Ubuntu Terminal display app version and instead runs it?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, version, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed WSL with Ubuntu after getting white fever from emulating an operating system inside an operating system. It was not enjoyable for me at all, really.

And here I am, trying to check out what version I have of VS Code, using:

```
code --version
```

...and then, to my surprise, the shell clogs for a wee bit...and VSC pops up.

As an extra bit of info: I've had two versions installed (July 2017 one and the most recent version), with the older one getting booted.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run that command from a cmd or powershell?

Comment: Also what happens if you do `code.exe --version` from WSL?

Comment: Both powershell and cmd return back VSC version: 1.14.2 along with a hash. Meanwhile WSL gives me a message that no such command was found.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I was unable to install code via the Ubuntu Terminal as no such package has been found. I tried intalling nodejs -- again to no avail, so no, I couldn't do that.

Comment: Link: 1. https://gist.github.com/fdmnio/604c6b811939468fdad06e3fbba942ed 2. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2760